# Extending a certain bound to the von Neumann tensor product

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

I am wondering whether the following is true: Let $H_1, H_2$ denote two Hilbert spaces and let $$\phi_i\colon B(H_1)\overline{\otimes}B(H_2)\to B(H_2)$$ be ultraweakly continuous, completely positive linear maps for $i\in \{1,2\}$.

Assume now that there exists $\varepsilon>0$ such that $\Vert \phi_1(x)-\phi_2(x)\Vert\leq \Vert x\Vert \varepsilon$ for every $x$ in the algebraic tensor product $B(H_1)\odot B(H_2)$. Can we then conclude that $\Vert \phi_1(y)-\phi_2(y)\Vert\leq \Vert y\Vert \varepsilon$ for every $y\in B(H_1)\overline{\otimes}B(H_2)$?

My guess: by boundedness of $\phi_1-\phi_2$, we can extend the above inequality to hold true for elements in the minimal tensor product $B(H_1)\otimes B(H_2)$. Then, ultraweak continuity and a possible application of Kaplansky (?) takes us  home.

I am unsure about all of this and would love some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct (or at least you mention the right ingredients).

More generally, if $\Phi\colon M\to N$ is an ultraweakly continuous linear map and $A\subset M$ is an ultraweakly dense $\ast$-subalgebra, then $\lVert \Phi\rVert=\lVert \Phi|_A\rVert$: Let $x\in M$ with $\lVert x\rVert\leq 1$. By Kaplansky's density theorem, there exists a net $(x_j)$ in $A$ such that $\lVert x_j\rVert\leq 1$ and $x_j\to x$ ultraweakly. Since $\Phi$ is ultraweakly continuous, it follows that $\Phi(x_j)\to \Phi(x)$ ultraweakly. Thus, if $\omega\in N_\ast$, then
$$
\lvert \omega(\Phi(x))\rvert=\lim_j \lvert \omega(\Phi(x_j))\rvert\leq \lVert \omega\rVert\liminf_j \lVert\Phi(x_j)\rVert\leq \lVert \omega\rVert\lVert \Phi|_A\rVert.
$$
Hence
$$
\lVert \Phi(x)\rVert=\sup_{\substack{\omega\in N_\ast\\\lVert \omega\rVert\leq 1}}\lvert \omega(\Phi(x))\rvert\leq \lVert \Phi|_A\rVert.
$$
Taking the supremum over all $x\in M$ with $\lVert x\rVert\leq 1$ gives $\lVert \Phi\rVert\leq \lVert \Phi|_A\rVert$, while the converse inequality is trivial.

Comment: Thank you for a very elaborate answer!

Comment: Sorry for returning to this after a while, but don't you assume that $B(H_1)\otimes B(H_2)$ is ultraweakly dense in the weak closure $B(H_1)\overline{\otimes}B(H_2)$? If so, how is this realized? Thank you again.

Comment: I prefer to define the von Neumann algebra tensor product as ultraweak (instead of weak) closure of the algebraic tensor product. In any case, it follows from elementary von Neumann algebra theory that the weak, ultraweak, strong and ultrastrong closure of a $\ast$-algebra all coincide.